# How to increment rows when inserting formula into cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a working section of VBA code, which inserts an array formula into a specific cell. The formula is an INDEX MATCH function.

```
For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell2 In row.Cells

    cell2.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C, MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A:A = A5)*(Sheet2!B:B=""Total""),0))"

Next cell2
Next row
```

Every time I insert the formula into a cell, I want to increment the row number for A5, so next A6. The formula is being inserted in a For Each loop.
In Excel this is represented as A$5.

What's the VBA equivalent?

Comment: Actually it's not `A$5`, it's `A5` so that the 5 will change to 6. You can put the formula into the whole range at once and it will change. Cut down your full column references if you only want to return from `C1:C6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just figured it out, so I'll post it anyway.

```
Static value As Integer
    value = 5

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell2 In row.Cells

cell2.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C, MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A:A = A " & value & ")*(Sheet2!B:B=""Total""),0))"

value = value + 1
  Next cell2
Next row
```